# Python Boto3 check if file on s3 is equal to local file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, boto3

I have some files in a local folder. These files can be modified locally. I need to keep a copy of the updated files on S3.
Is there a way I can check whether a local file is equal to a file on S3 (example: using checksum)? In this way I won't have to upload the files that have not been changed.
I am using boto3 and Python.

Comment: Also be aware of the `aws s3 sync` feature of the awscli.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 objects have an **entity tag (ETag)** that "represents a specific version of that object". It is a calculated checksum, which you can compare to an equivalently calculated checksum on the local objects.

See: [Using Content-MD5 and the ETag to verify uploaded objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html#checking-object-integrity-etag-and-md5)

I would suggest first checking the **length** of the files, because it is very simple and a different length indicates the files are not the same. Then, calculate the ETag of the local object and compare it with the ETag on the S3 object.

However, the ETag is **not** an MD5 if the object is encrypted, and buckets are now using encryption by default. Therefore, the ETag method might not work on your particular bucket -- try some experiments to confirm whether it is applicable. Worst case, you could always calculate an MD5 before upload, and then store the MD5 as Metadata on the object during the upload. You could use this to compare files in future.

S3 can even do this for you. See: [New – Additional Checksum Algorithms for Amazon S3 | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-additional-checksum-algorithms-for-amazon-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also compute the ETag of a local file. But this is based on a few assumptions:

- Does not account for additional encryption like customer-provided keys (SSE-C) or server-side encryption using KMS keys [(see here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html#large-object-checksums:%7E:text=its%20object%20data.-,If%20an%20object%20is%20created%20by%20the%20PUT%20Object%2C%20POST,ETag%20that%20is%20not%20an%20MD5%20digest%20of%20its%20object%20data.,-If%20an%20object)
- Assumes multipart uploads use the same chunk size

**Calculating "ETag" of local file**

```py
import hashlib

from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional
import boto3



def get_local_etag(path: Path, chunk_size_bytes: Optional[int] = None) -> str:
    """Calculates an expected AWS s3 upload etag for a local on-disk file.
    Takes into account multipart uploads, but does NOT account for additional encryption
    (like KMS keys)
    """

    if chunk_size_bytes is None:
        # This is used by `aws s3 cp` function
        file_size = path.stat().st_size
        chunk_size_bytes = 8 * 1024 * 1024  # 8 MB
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html
        while math.ceil(file_size / chunk_size_bytes) > 10000: # 
            chunk_size_bytes *= 2
    
    md5s = []

    with open(path, "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            data = fp.read(chunk_size_bytes)
            if not data:
                break
            md5s.append(hashlib.md5(data))

    if len(md5s) > 1:  # We are dealing with a multipart upload
        digests = b"".join(m.digest() for m in md5s)
        multipart_md5 = hashlib.md5(digests)
        expected_etag = f'"{multipart_md5.hexdigest()}-{len(md5s)}"'
    elif len(md5s) == 1:  # File smaller than chunk size
        expected_etag = f'"{md5s[0].hexdigest()}"'
    else:  # Empty file
        expected_etag = f'"{hashlib.md5().hexdigest()}"'

    return expected_etag
```

**Identifying the multipart upload chunk size of S3 object**

```py
def determine_multipart_chunk_size(bucket: str, key: str) -> Optional[int]:
    """Determines the multipart chunk size for a given S3 path, if it is a multipart upload"""
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    head_object = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, PartNumber=1)
    if head_object.get("PartsCount", 1) > 1 and "ContentLength" in head_object:
        return head_object["ContentLength"]
    return None
```

**Lastly, a function that checks if local file and s3 object are in sync**

```py
def check_sync_status(bucket: str, key: str, local_path: Path) -> bool:
    """Checks whether transfer from source to destination is required"""

    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    
    s3_object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    local_stats = local_path.stat()
    
    source_size_bytes = s3_object.content_length
    dest_size_bytes = local_stats.st_size
    if source_size_bytes != dest_size_bytes:
        return True
    
    source_last_modified = s3_object.last_modified
    dest_last_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(local_stats.st_mtime, tz=timezone.utc)
    if source_last_modified.replace(microsecond=0) > dest_last_modified.replace(microsecond=0):
        return True
    
    source_hash = s3_object.e_tag
    dest_hash = get_local_etag(dest_local_path, determine_multipart_chunk_size(bucket, key))
    if source_hash != dest_hash:
        return True
    return False
```

**References**:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html#large-object-checksums

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, boto3's s3 client doesn't return the checksum value without actually downloading the files. One workaround is to use the last modified timestamp: you can use the `LastModified` info that is returned in the list_objects call and compare it to the last modification time of the local file.

Since you are using python, one way to get modification time of a file would be:

```
import os
os.path.getmtime(path)
```